# how to filter a bi report dropdown with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to select an item in the drop-down, and I'm not able to, it stops at the drop-down part and doesn't select the item I want, which in this case is to clear what is written and filter it again, which stays within the drop-down. Can you help me?? Thank you very much.

Dropdown that I want to filter:

[image: dropdown that I want to filter]

[html code of the search bar I want to clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9hQ7.png)"
`

`

```
`import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

arquivo_excel = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=\[("Arquivos Excel", "\*.xlsx")\])
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('power bi report')
driver.set_window_size(1200,600)

time.sleep(5) #Go to the second page of the report
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i\[@class='glyphicon glyph-small pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium middleIcon active'\]").click()

time.sleep(5) #open the dropdown
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i\['@class=slicer-dropdown-popup visual themeableElement'\]").click()

time.sleep(5) #this is the part where the code breaks, when I try to clear the search bar
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i\['@class=searchInput'\]").clear()
```